# Does sequential clock gating useful?

Tags: clock, synthesis

I know there is clock gating method that xor-ing the input and output of FF, and use that signal as clock enable. (figure 1, i'll call it xor-ing from now)

I'm now studying sequential clock gating. I can't understand why sequential clock gating such as using STC or ODC condition is useful.

I think clock gating some serial FFs through STC condition gets the same result of gating them by xor-ing each input and output of FFs. In case of ODC condition, i think it could be effective because clk of FFs can be gated while input/output of FFs are not equal, which cannot be gated by xor-ing.

In case of STC condition, however, i cannot understand why it is useful. Let's say there are three serial FFs,  FF1, FF2 and FF3. When FF1 is stable, FF2 can be clock gated in the next timeframe, and then FF3 can be clock gated next, as sequential clock gating through STC conditioin says. My question is, does it get more power reduction than just xor-ing three FFs respectively?
I studied this problem for a few days, but still I didn't get answer.

[image]

figure1: XOR-ing the input/output of FF, generate clock enable signal

Comment: What do "STC" and "ODC" stand for?

Comment: ODC is observability don't care, and STC is stability condition. Here are some simple descriptions about them: http://electronicdesign.com/power/reduce-power-chip-designs-sequential-clock-gating